# How can I make a desktop app with node.js in the backend for APIs

Tags: node.js, desktop-application

What would be the best set of technologies to use if I want to make a desktop application which would fetch data from server through JSON (node.js with MYSQL).

Side note: Currently we are using angular.js for frontend but the client wants a desktop app and is adamant. Don't want to change anything server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go ahead with js itself then you might want to look into [electronjs](https://electronjs.org/) you can even combine it with other frontend techs such as Angular, React or VueJs.

Another option is [NW.js](https://nwjs.io/).

Look into both and choose as per your requirements both have pros and cons.

Comment: electron JS looks like it may just do the trick. If I migrate my frontend from HTML/Angular.js to electron based desktop app with node.js on server, can it also have offline capabilities ? so that user can keep working without net connection and sync data when it comes back on.

Comment: for offline capabilities I am not sure about how you can do it with a database like MySQL maybe you could use SQLite and sync it based on your convenience, but in NoSQL PouchDB is probably the best shot. PouchDB can be synced with couch server.

Comment: ya, that can work, thanks man